# Avoid losing this reference and why it's happening

Tags: javascript, callback, this, module-pattern

I have this fiddle which has an error --> http://jsfiddle.net/Osoascam/AkZZr/6/
(This is the version without the error) --> http://jsfiddle.net/Osoascam/AkZZr/7/

In it, there is a Module (like the main application), a `Module.AjaxInterface` which deals with Ajax calls, a `Module.Modules.Inbox` (which performs tasks related to email inbox), and a  `Module.Pages.Gmail` which deals with several modules to show a page. All of this is done using the Module Pattern.

Now, you can see there are a LOT of callbacks. I'd like to know what happens to `this` on these calls...

What I don't get is what is happening to `this` reference and how can I preserve it:

```
getMessages: function(params) {
                var parameters = params || {};
                params = {
                    // Please note I'm using this, which equals the module
                    successCallback: this.pretendRender,
                    successCallbackParameters: parameters,
                    json: params.json
                };
                var test = new Module.AjaxInterface(params);
                test.ajaxCall();
            },
```

So, the call to a function inside the module itself works... Then, it calls `test.ajaxCalls`, which in return calls `pretendRender()`. Now, on `pretendRende`r I have this:

```
 pretendRender: function(data, parameters) {
                // LINE 106 that is causing the ERROR
                // It says "this.addColor() is not defined and THIS = window now
                data.color = this.addColor();
                parameters.successCallback(data);
            },

            addColor: function() {
              return "#AD9";
           }
```

My question is... What is happening to `this` reference? Why is it changing to `window`? How can I fix it? I know I could use `call` or `apply`, but the function `pretendRender` is being called on `AjaxInterface`, and the reference to `Modules.Inbox` has been lost (unless I use `caller`, which I can't under `"strict"`). I know I can pass `this` to `AjaxInterface` to preserve it, but what I really want is to truly understand what is going on and create an elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.pretendRender` is just a reference/pointer to a function, the context of `this` when the function is called depends on many things:

```
a.b.c = this.pretendRender;
a.b.c();
```

`this` will be `b` inside `c` because the function referenced by `c` is being called as a property of `b`

---

```
window.a = this.pretendRender;
a();
```

`this` will be set to the `global object` because the function referenced by `a` is being called  as a property of the `global object`

---

```
a.b.c = this.pretendRender.bind( this );
a.b.c();
```

`this` will be the original `this` inside `c` no matter what because the function referenced by `c` is a bound function that calls the original function with context set to the original `this`. `.bind` exists in modern browsers but [must be included to be sure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) it's available.

---

```
a.b.c = this.pretendRender;
a.b.c.call( someObject );
```

`this` will be `someObject` inside `c` because it is explicitly given.

---

Since you are using jQuery, instead of `this.pretendRender.bind( this );` you can use `successCallback: $.proxy( this.pretendRender, this )`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AkZZr/8/)

Comment: Mmmm... I get it... It's not that I want "this" to be inside the callback... I just need a way to call addColor()... And it says it's undefined if I just leave it as is

Comment: You call `this.addColor()` and it will work when `this` is set properly. So: `successCallback: $.proxy( this.pretendRender, this )` if you are using jQuery is the only thing you need to change and it should work.. See here http://jsfiddle.net/AkZZr/8/. I did that only change and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is always the object the function is being called on.  It changes.  `this.pretendRender` is not a method attached to the `this` object at that point in time.  It's just a function being passed.  If you want to guarantee that `this` in that context travels with the method, you need to **bind** `this` to that function.  Something like this (using a closure):

```
var me = this;
params = {
    successCallback: function() { return me.pretendRender.apply(me, arguments); },
    ...
}
```

The underscore.js framework has a considerably better way of doing this with `_.bind()`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation...
But I'm doing successCallback: `this.pretendRender`, (that is, passing the reference to that function rather than calling the function itself). If I do this `me.pretendRender.apply(me, arguments);`, wouldn't I be calling the function?

Besides, the arguments to that function are applied on `Module.AjaxInterface` and that function is executed there, calling its reference in `callback(data, parameters);`

That is why I don't know how to use apply, as the function reference is passed and then executed in another module.

Comment: it would get called if not for the `function() {...}` wrapping the call.  That creates an anonymous function which will get called later that saves the `this` reference in the `me` variable.

Comment: Ok, I tried `successCallback:  function(data) { return me.pretendRender.call(me, data);`, which returned `addColor is not defined`. (on this js fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/Osoascam/AkZZr/9/ )